# Combine Rests in Finale

Tags: software, rests, finale

I want to combine the two highlighted rests in the picture into a dotted-eighth rest with a single command.  Is it possible?  I'm using Finale 2014d (Mac).

[image: An eighth rest followed by a sixteenth rest at the start of a measure]

Comment: Can you not just create a dotted eighth rest?

Comment: I have thousands of these.  (OK maybe hundreds.)  The result of MIDI import.  I actually know the answer now so will answer my own question if no one else does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the MIDI/Audio menu -> Quantization Settings... -> More Settings -> check "Minimize Number of Rests" and check "Allow Dotted Rests in Simple Meters"

Then highlight the measures you want to affect and run MIDI/Audio -> Retranscribe.